# Test: Crawler DateTimeType: date_widet and time_widget

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, domcrawler

I have a DateTimeWidget rendered by 2 fields:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('datetime', DateTimeType::class, [
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
        ]);
```

It generates as needed 2 field widget:

```
<input type="text" id="form_datetime_date" name="form[datetime][date]">
<input type="text" id="form_datetime_time" name="form[datetime][time]">
```

**It works perfectly using the UI.**

During my functional test, i want to submit the form having this input.

I tried

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('my_submit')->form();
$form['form']['datetime'];
```

and

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('my_submit')->form();
$form['form']['datetime']['date'] = new \DateTime('tomorrow');
$form['form']['datetime']['time'] = new \DateTime('tomorrow');
```

Writing this question I found the solution, I let it here if it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

It has to be filled as text separately

```
$form->disableValidation();
$values = $form->getPhpValues();

$form['form']['datetime'] = [
    'date'=> (new \DateTime('tomorrow'))->format('d/m/Y'),
    'time'=> (new \DateTime('tomorrow'))->format('H:i'),
];

$crawler = $client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values, $form->getPhpFiles());
```